# Complex Integration with Cauchy Formula

Tags: complex-analysis, cauchy-integral-formula

This exercise is taken from E. Freitag, Complex Analysis.

Compute, using the Cauchy integral theorem and the Cauchy integral formula, the following integrals:
\begin{align*}
\int_{\gamma} \frac{\mathrm{e}^{-z}}{(z+2)^{3}}\mathrm{d}z  
\end{align*}
with $\gamma(t)= 3 \mathrm{e}^{2\pi i t }$ $t\in [0,1]$. I calculated 
\begin{align*}
\int_{\gamma} \frac{\mathrm{e}^{-z}}{(z+2)^{3}}\mathrm{d}z  = 2 \pi i \mathrm{e}^{2} 
\end{align*}
but in the solutions they calculated $\pi i \mathrm{e}^{2} $ ? I don't find the mistake.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Take $f(z)=e^{-z}$. Then using the Cauchy integral formula $$\int_\gamma\frac{e^{-z}}{(z+2)^3}dz=\int_\gamma\frac{f(z)}{(z-(-2))^{2+1}}dz=\frac{2\pi i}{2!}f^{(2)}(-2)=\pi if^{(2)}(-2).$$ Now note that $f^{(2)}(z)=e^{-z}$.

Comment: Quite simple, I skipped out that the pole has order of three. Thanks for opening my eyes.